# How to modify appearance of HTML on window resize?

Tags: html, css

Very simply put I want to display a html table, when the window is larger than 900px, or so. How would I do so?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

You can use a media query to hide the element on smaller viewports.

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: @idrumgood No they're not but they do point people in the right direction to have a go at learning for them selves to begin with. +1 for both answers.

Answer (score 2):

Two options, Media queries or javascript.

Media Query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 900px) { ... }
```

Put your specific code to show it in that file.

Javascript:

```
if(document.width >= 900){ /*display content*/ }
```

In the JS case, you may need to attach an event listener for a window resize.